# In Android which method to lazy load images is better suited for performance?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've gone through the questions on stackoverflow.Implementing multi-threading and giving the task of downloading successive images to successive threads seems to be the weapon of choice,however wouldn't spawning,say 10 threads at a time to download 10 images within the visible portion of the screen affect performance of the application as opposed to letting a single thread download all the 10 images? (I'm attempting to download only those images which are visible at that instant of time on the screen)
Yes I'm a newbie at android programming and yes i know that multi-threading in most cases is always faster,but is the time difference between the timings of the two methods in this case (only 10 images at a time)appreciable enough to take the extra effort and the increase in code complexity?

Ive also visited http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d4ba513a5fa90029 it however doesn't seem to shed any light on it.

Any answers will be largely appreciated.
Cheers !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 background threads downloading images wouldn't slow you scroll speed (I think this is you care about) but spawning this 10 threads will. So for the sake of performance it's better to be careful about amount of threads you spawn. I can tell that in one of my applications I managed to receive a significant increase in performance by spawning less threads. Of course code should be as simple as possible to beat the task. But not simpler.